# What should I do when my edit is approved but the reviewer breaks the formatting?

Tags: support, edits, specific-question

I formatted this question https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70603458/revisions and a user reviewed my changes to the question and accepted my edits, but it looks like after they reviewed the edit, the formatting got messed up.

Is this an error of the process to approve editions?

Should I edit the question again?

Comment: It looks like the user who made the edit after you made a mistake. I've rolled back to the version you edited now. BTW, you can ping editors (the username after @ won't auto-complete, so you'll need to spell it correctly), and ask them for clarifications.

Comment: You did nothing wrong, the person that approved it made a mistake, it's been fixed for you, no need to worry.

Comment: Looks like it's an honest mistake by the reviewer. They missed a single tick character on the first code block while adding the code highlighting hint (see the side-by-side markdown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit was accepted with what's called "Improve edit", which effectively means that the reviewer approves your edit and then appends an edit on top of it. You can see this in the post history where it shows up as 2 separate edits.

They made a mistake in their edit, so it's not really related to you at this point. You can edit it again if it's just a minor mistake, or otherwise flag with a custom flag explaining the issue and request a *rollback*.

Though if you want to minimize the workload of reviewers and moderators, you could also just poke your head into the [SO Close Vote Reviewers chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and explain the issue there. Someone with full edit privileges will likely be able to fix the rollback instantly. In general, it's a good place to ask if you are uncertain how to flag something.

Comment: 1) You could also mention pinging the editor again and asking them directly to review their edit. 2) It's worth mentioning that SOCVR has rules about asking for action on posts that one is involved with. While this particular instance may, or may not, be within the rules, it's a good idea to not give the impression that SOCVR can be used to handle issues with one's own actions.

Comment: @cigien You can't ping them unless they've left a comment or such below the post.

Comment: As per the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019) anyone who has edited a post can be pinged. The name won't auto-complete so it appears as if it's not possible, but the editor should get a notification if the username is spelled correctly.

Comment: @cigien Ok I didn't know that or at least I've never had any success with getting replies when I've tried. I quite often write `@user` when someone does an incorrect edit to let them know what was wrong. I can't recall getting a response, ever.

Comment: Yeah, that's certainly possible. There's no mechanism to ensure that a user actually responds to a ping :) But they will get notified, and in cases where there's a simple typo like the one in the OP's question, I expect any reasonable editor would correct it, even if they don't choose to respond.